# Custom colors for different rowkeys in StackedBarchart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

In this jfreechart example, colors for each rowkey(ABZPROD) is the same, when all rowkey are same:

```
   dataset.addValue(32.4, "ABZPROD", "Category 1");
   dataset.addValue(43.2, "ABZPROD", "Category 2");
   dataset.addValue(23.0, "ABZPROD", "Category 3");
   dataset.addValue(13.0, "ABZPROD", "Category 4");
```

[image]

But when i change these rowkeys to different(ABZPROD1,ABZPROD2,ABZPROD3 etc), colors are changing. How can i prevent that happening? I want to set my values like below and want colors same for each rowkey. Unfortunately when i run it, every color is different for each rowkey(ABZPROD1 is red, ABZPROD2 is blue etc.)

```
   dataset.addValue(32.4, "ABZPROD1", "Category 1");
   dataset.addValue(43.2, "ABZPROD2", "Category 2");
   dataset.addValue(23.0, "ABZPROD3", "Category 3");
   dataset.addValue(13.0, "ABZPROD4", "Category 4");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest  way is to use `AbstractRenderer#setSeriesPaint`

If you added the series first you can do this:

```java
StackedBarRenderer renderer = (StackedBarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.RED);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.RED);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(3, Color.RED);
```

[image]

Comment: That's very useful. But what about second or third values (17.8,15.6,11.3,11.8). How can i set them into a same color?

Comment: The same way, set the series paint.  If each series shares a common name I might write a new renderer

Comment: Yeah my series partially has same name. For example (xy1, xy12, xy234) as you can see "xy" is common word in each series. but xy may not be on each category, there are other series such as (xz1,xz3 or yz2,yz4) as well.